# button BackgroundColor does not change as expected

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Button BackgroundColor cannot change using ResourceDictionary style

in App.xaml

```
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="WarningButtonBackGroundColor">#eb8916</Color>
            
            <Style x:Key="WarningButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource WarningButtonBackGroundColor}"></Setter>
            </Style>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

in page.xaml

```
<Button Text="Delete" Style="{StaticResource WarningButtonStyle}"></Button>
```

button BackgroundColor did not as expected

Comment: Works here , can you show us your Page.xaml code . Is it showing any color ? iOS or Android or all.

Comment: @BasH it's showing the system default color on Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still the same output.

App.xaml

```
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="WarningButtonBackGroundColor">#eb8916</Color>
        <Style x:Key="WarningButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource WarningButtonBackGroundColor}" />
        </Style>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

MainPage.xaml

```
 <Button Style="{StaticResource WarningButtonStyle}" Text="Delete" />
```

[image]